# Crazy problem with bootstrap navbar and carousel

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, navbar

I am using 3 different css styles on my webpage and they are in the following order -

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/styles.css" %}">
```

That third style (it contains some minor esthetic changes for the carousel) is probably not relevant in regards of this problem. (i have tested it)

The problem is - I want the navbar and the carousel (both still kind of unfinished) to be displayed correctly, but when all of my 3 styles are running, then the carousel is fine, but the navbar changes it´s shape to strange proportions.
When I disable that first style, then the navbar is fine, but the carousel is messed up and it´s images are displaying one on top of another and the buttons for changing the slides are missing.

This is the image of intended navbar - (being on top of the webpage)
[image]

And this is the image of messed up navbar -
[image]

Here is the navbar code -

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top col-6'>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Janko</a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'hobbieswithCSS' %}">My hobbies</a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'contactmewithCSS' %}">Contact me</a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'basic_app:register' %}">Register</a></li>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a class='navbar-link' href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}">Login</a></li>
        {% endif %}

      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And here is the carousel code -

```
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carouselExampleIndicators">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"></li>
      <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"></li>
      <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img alt="First slide" class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Jn0X0pDS/1.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5 class="animated bounceInRight" style="animation-delay: 1s">Web Development</h5>
          <p class="animated bounceInLeft" style="animation-delay: 2s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.</p>
          <p class="animated bounceInRight" style="animation-delay: 3s"><a href="#">More Info</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img alt="Second slide" class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.postimg.cc/SQXZtrTZ/2.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5 class="animated slideInDown" style="animation-delay: 1s">web design</h5>
          <p class="animated fadeInUp" style="animation-delay: 2s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.</p>
          <p class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay: 3s"><a href="#">More Info</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img alt="Third slide" class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.postimg.cc/Jh4x3cH5/3.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5 class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay: 1s">Digital Marketing</h5>
          <p class="animated fadeInLeft" style="animation-delay: 2s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.</p>
          <p class="animated zoomIn" style="animation-delay: 3s"><a href="#">More Info</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><a class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a> <a
      class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"><span aria-hidden="true" class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
  </div>
```

I know, that this is kind of mind-boggling and it is unusual to use 2 different bootstrap styles at once, but I was trying my best to make my carousel work properly, but I would like to achieve it without having problems with the navbar. Could anyone help me please? Thank You very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top'>
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Janko</a>
    <ul class="nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="#">My hobbies</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="#">Contact me</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="#}">Register</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class='navbar-link' href="#">Logout</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="#">Login</a></li>

    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form form-inline" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

you had `navbar-nav` class on the `ul` which meant that it had `flex-direction:column`. You also had `col-6` to the `nav` element so it would never all fit along the top on desktop, I've removed this.

Also I've added `mr-auto` to the `ul` to push it to the left.

I have taken the `navbar-brand` outside of the `ul` as [Bootstrap documentation] (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) also does this, I think it causes problems in alignment otherwise. At least it did when I tested.

I've added the class `nav-item` to the `li` elements too, as in Bootstrap docs.

Everything works as intended.

I removed `navbar-left` from the form as it's going to sit near the right from what I can see in your screenshot. I added `form-inline` to it to get the search button on the same level.

May just need some final tidying up but that's fixed the issue.

**will need more clarification on what the issue with the carousel is**
I imagine calling two different bootstrap stylesheets isn't helping though, remove the older version.

Comment: Thank You very much, Joe! It took me hours and I could not still find the solution and You have found it in a matter of a few minutes. :O I am really grateful to You. :D

Comment: I have upvoted the answer, although it is not publicly visible, (my reputation would have to be 15+) but You have really helped me. :P

Comment: Hey you're welcome, thanks :) Happy coding!

Comment: Dear Joe, check Your email. I have sent You a message. :-)